# Visualization of function of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, bounded-variation

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a real valued function If $f$ is not differentiable at a point say at $c$ then in the graph of $f$ we get a corner. So by looking at the graph we can say that whether $f$ is differentiable at a point or not. My question is can we detect whether a function $f$ is of bounded variation or not just by looking at it's graph? How can we relate bounded variation with graph.

We can also define functions of bounded variation for a function of real variables having complex valued image,i.e. for $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb C$ How can we do the same for above type of functions?

Comment: how do you draw a function that doesn't have bounded variation? even something simple like $x\sin 1/x$?

Comment: "If $f$ is not differentiable at a point say at $c$ then in the graph of $f$ we get a corner" this is true if $f$ is differentiable near $c$. Take, for example, the Weierstrass function: does it have a corner at every point? What do we mean by that? The geometrical interpretation is nice only as long as $f$ is a nice function